# Suppose I need to make an app similar to truecaller and my backend database is mongodb. Performance Vs Storage?

Tags: mongodb, database

lets take example of **TrueCaller** app. Suppose I need to make an app with similar function and my backend database is mongodb. So each time a user installs my app around 1000 contacts get added to the database. **(Suppose I already have 10000 phonenumbers)** Since I dont want same phonenumber  to be stored twice what I do is I check whether the number is present already. Thus a total of **1000x10000=10million** comparisons may take place. 10million comparisons from 1 user. Now suppose 10 users install simultaneously. it becomes 100 million comparisons. *So should I just add all numbers to the database directly without any comparisons?*

Comment: Just create a unique index on that field. Also, don't assume everyone knows what it is that some random app does.

Comment: By adding unique field an error pops up as soon as same number is added twice. So rest of the numbers are not added.

Comment: yeah, so? Handle that error and continue.

Comment: Yes!!. Incase an error pops up, how to handle it and whether it is possible to update the name of the existing user. Acually the app save the user name and phonenumber just as a phone directory. So I want My app to handle the error and update the name when same phone number pops up. Could you help me with the code??

Comment: No. Consult the documentation (on exception handling, in particular) for whatever programming language you're using. Also, take a look at [ask] page. It has a ton of good advice on how to ask good questions.